# How do you set a default song to play in the helicopter?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

In Metal Gear Solid 5: The Phantom Pain, when you take-off or land, you can set a default song to play. How do you do that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are a couple of things involved in having your helicopter play music out loud.

First, you must develop a loudspeaker for the helicopter itself, by going to **iDroid > Mother Base > Development > Helicopter**:
[image]

[image]

Since the SPEAKER development is an upgrade, denoted by the giant plus sign on the right side of its icon, you do *not* need to equip it explicitly. Once development is complete, the helicopter automatically has the loudspeaker built into it.

Now you can now assign music in the **iDroid > Missions > Cassette Tapes** screen:

[image]

Once you have the desired song highlighted, the button to press is **Square** (on the PS4) for **Set Helicopter Music** . Your platform will show the appropriate key bind at the bottom there.

I have heard that players on PC can import custom music of their own, but I haven't had any direct experience with that process myself.

Comment: A note for PC players: the game's folder contains a "CustomSoundtracks" folder. You can drop mp3 files in here, and they will show up ingame among the music tapes.

Comment: Basically anything by AC/DC is a *great* soundtrack for this game.